# Creating Custom Field in Orchard CMS to render Dropdown from a separate module

Tags: orchardcms

I'm creating website using OrchardCMS and here I want to have a dropdown in custom form. 
I have created a module to which I make an ajax call and it returns dropdown populated with db fetched values. 
All I need is to use this dropdown in custom form. I'm figuring out how I can make it happen?
I have tried creating custom field using this link http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-a-custom-field-type but I'm still find my self no where. There should be some way to do this. 
Please guide me how I can go about it. I appreciate your response.
Thanks
Sohaib

Comment: What do you mean with 'in custom form'? What went wrong with creating the field?

Comment: In orchard we have a module name as Custom Form so I have enabled that form and we can simply add fields to that form. Now All I need is to render my dropdown field in that form. So For that I want you to guide me about it. what is the best solution in this case.

Comment: I think creating a custom field would be the way to go, what went wrong or what didn't work?

Comment: I just created using this link and it is for date time field creation. http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-a-custom-field-type and I want to crate a  dropdown field so I can not understand how I can go about it.

Comment: Also do you know where I can get help about orchard? Any forum or something you have idea about..

Comment: You can get help at official documentation (http://docs.orchardproject.net/) stackoverflow, gitter (https://gitter.im/OrchardCMS/Orchard), codeplex (https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a field for this.

MyModule/Fields/MyCustomField.cs:

```
public class MyCustomField : ContentField {
    public string SelectedValue {
        get { return Storage.Get<string>(); }
        set { Storage.Set(value); }
    }
}
```

MyModule/Drivers/MyCustomFieldDriver.cs:

```
public class MyCustomFieldDriver : ContentFieldDriver<MyCustomField> {

    // EditorTemplates/Fields/MyCustom.cshtml
    private const string TemplateName = "Fields/MyCustom";

    private static string GetPrefix(ContentField field, ContentPart part) {
        // handles spaces in field names
        return (part.PartDefinition.Name + "." + field.Name)
               .Replace(" ", "_");
    }

    protected override DriverResult Display(ContentPart part, MyCustomField field, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        return ContentShape("Fields_MyCustom",
            field.Name,
            f => f.Name(field.Name)
                .SelectedValue(field.SelectedValue));
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(ContentPart part, MyCustomField field, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        return ContentShape("Fields_MyCustom_Edit", () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
            TemplateName: TemplateName,
            Model: field,
            Prefix: GetPrefix(field, part)));
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(ContentPart part, MyCustomField field, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(field, GetPrefix(field, part), null, null);
        return Editor(part, field, shapeHelper);
    }
}
```

MyModule/Views/Fields/MyCustom.cshtml:

```
@{ 
    var selectedValue = Model.SelectedValue;
}

<h1>@selectedValue</h1>
```

MyModule/Views/EditorTemplates/Fields/MyCustom.cshtml:

```
@model MyModule.Fields.MyCustomField

<select id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedValue)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.SelectedValue)"></select>

@using (Script.Foot()) {
    Script.Require("jQuery");

    <script>

        $(function () {
            // your own url ofcourse
            var url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
                dd = $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedValue)");

            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function () {
                    dd.append("<option value='" + this.name + "'>" + this.name + "</option>");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

MyModule/Placement.info:

```
<Placement>
  <Place Fields_MyCustom_Edit="Content:3" />
  <Place Fields_MyCustom="Content:3" />
</Placement>
```

And that should be all :)

Comment: Thank you so much for all these I'm very much pleased with this help. It has cleared lot of things. Could you please let me know that in the class inside model public class MyCustomField  property SelectedValue
is null when I execute this code after inserting this custom field in form. 
and then it throws exception saying 

Line 10:     @Html.DropDownListFor(widget => widget.LayerId, new SelectList(Model.AvailableLayers, "Id", "Name"))

in Modules\Orchard.Widgets\Views\EditorTemplates\Parts.Widgets.WidgetPart.cshtml    Line: 10
I need to know where this variable gets value for the first time?

Comment: Please accept this answer if you find it solved your original question. If you encounter more problems please create a new question and provide some more details :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution dear. It worked for me. Could you please tell me is there any way I can connect with orchard guys?

Comment: Could you please tell me if I want to configure this dropdown how should I go about it.  I need to filter data in dropdown so for that I want to configure it from admin and would like to send that configuration in the ajax call above.. thanks

Comment: See this link: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-a-custom-field-type for field scope settings, or this link: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Adding-custom-settings if you want to have site-scope settings instead of per field

Comment: Yes thanks, have followed the same link to solve my problem. Thank you so much.